# Sitefinity 4.4 - Dynamically change page title and description at runtime

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-4

Does anyone know how to dynamically change the page title in Sitefinity from a regular user control?

Our scenario is simple. We have a real estate website with a search feature. On the search results page we have a control showing the search results, but we need to be able to change the Page title, description and keywords based on the search performed.

We posted on Telerik, but they gave vague answers and pointed us to incorrect objects or objects that didn't actually work.

?

Regards,
Jacques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've usually done this in the past is by using an external widget template.

By mapping your widget template to an external file, you can use a full User Control (.ascx file) which means you can also run code behind.

From there it's just a matter of running something like

```
Page.Title = "whatever";
```

For more info on using an external template for Sitefinity Widgets, check out this post: http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/joshmorales/posts/11-05-10/mapping_external_templates_for_sitefinity_4_widgets.aspx

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Hi Josh, I actually got to the point of just doing a normal user control and then using Page.Title and it worked. It's weird though because in Sitefinity 3.7 we were told by Telerik to make use of the InternalPage object to get this right and now it's back to something as simple as this. Seems almost too good to be true

Comment: Question: Why would you have to map a widget template at all if the user control us my own custom control?

Comment: you only have to use a widget template if you are wanting to customize one of the built in Sitefinity widgets like BlogPosts or News

Comment: So in this case you could just use a normal User Control for your own custom control and set the Page Title with the Page property of the userControl?

Comment: you certainly could. the only reason I suggested the widget template is so that you don't have a stray control on the page just for updating the title. If you make it part of the widget template it keeps everything tidy. but absolutely you could make a custom control that does this as well.